# DataGrid does not updating with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm trying to learn MVVM (Using MVVMLight Toolkit). But i'm stuck.

In  ViewModel have an ObservableCollection

```
private ObservableCollection<Phone> _phoneNumbers;

public ObservableCollection<Phone> PhoneNumbers
{
    get { return _phoneNumbers; }
    private set
    {
        _phoneNumbers = value;
    }
}
```

In ViewModel constructor fill it in such way  `PhoneNumbers = new ObservableCollection<Phone>(Guest.Person.Phones);`

In view have

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PhoneNumbersDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="86" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneNumbers, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Header="Phone Number" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Guest.DeletePhoneCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">Delete</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In DeletePhoneCommand I'm trying to change `PhoneNumbers` e.g.

```
PhoneNumbers = new ObservableCollection<Phone>();
RaisePropertyChanged("PhoneNumbers");
```

Collection became empty but datagrid displays filled collection without any changes. "get" of Collection fires only when view is loading. Even when i  `RaisePropertyChanged("PhoneNumbers")` it doesn't fire.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to notify the changes to your collection you should use `Mode = TwoWay`

Two way will enable any change in object is reflected to the UI and any change in UI is reflected in the object.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PhoneNumbersDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="86" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneNumbers, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber,Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Phone Number" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Guest.DeletePhoneCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: The default-binding-mode is TwoWay

Comment: @Tomtom He has explicitly put as OneWay

Comment: You may also want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged e.g...

xaml - `ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneNumbers, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

c# - 

`set
{
 _phoneNumbers = value;
 OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumbers");
}`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the binding is broken when you reinitialize the collection. to fix this you will have to work on the already initialized collection. e.g :

clear the list using the

`PhoneNumbers.Clear()`

to add to the list, using

`PhoneNumbers.Add(item)`

you don't need to raise the property changed event to update the list in the UI when you're using ObservableCollection. You will need it if you change a property of the item on the list.

Answer (score 0):

at first clear the list with

```
Clear()
```

then add item

```
PhoneNumbers.Add(item)
```

Comment: Please read [how to give a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In particular here you could have indicated where to add these lines of code.